# some fields are not send to the database when making a react post request to a node backend api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMWbd.png)
this is the error ,the data is being shared across from step one `enter code here`form up to step five

```
enter code here



//register user after submit details
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        const { user } = props
        //update image selected to the user
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', files[0]);

        const updatedData = {
            ...user,
            image: files[0].name

        };

        //register user
        await axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/api/auth/register`, { ...user, ...updatedData });

        Swal.fire('Awesome!', "You're successfully registered!", 'success').then(
            (result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed || result.isDismissed) {
                    props.resetUser();
                    navigate('/user/login');
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        if (error.response) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: error.response.data
            });
            console.log('error', error.response.data);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please do not share screen shots of errors. Instead copy and paste them here

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab in the browser to see wich data you are sending in the body. If the email is not present in the request, then try to log the `props.user`